# How to increase query speed with multiple joins and if conditions

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement to generate a report from db, to get the transactions done by each supplier for a particular buyer. Below is the code to get the details:

```
    public Page<TopSupplierItemsDTO> getTopSuppliers(BusinessReportRequestDTO businessReportRequestDTO, Long buyerId, Pageable pageable) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); public Page<TopSupplierItemsDTO> getTopSuppliers(BusinessReportRequestDTO businessReportRequestDTO, Long buyerId, Pageable pageable) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("SELECT sum(amount),supplier.company_name "+
            "FROM purchase_order\n" +
            "LEFT JOIN process_order ON process_order.id=purchase_order.process_order_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN items ON items.id=process_order.items_id ") ;
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()) {
            stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN item_group ON items.item_group_id=item_group.id  ");
        }
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()) {
            stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN main_item_group ON item_group.main_item_group_id=main_item_group.id  ");
        }
        stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN supplier ON items.supplier_id=supplier.id  " +
            "LEFT JOIN buyer_business ON process_order.buyer_business_id = buyer_business.id   ");
        stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN business_supplier_mapping on business_supplier_mapping.supplier_id=supplier.id and business_supplier_mapping.buyer_business_id=process_order.buyer_business_id ");
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getFromDate()!=null && businessReportRequestDTO.getToDate()!=null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(" WHERE (purchase_order.deleted is null OR purchase_order.deleted is false) AND purchase_order.received_date BETWEEN '"+businessReportRequestDTO.getFromDate()+"' AND  '"+businessReportRequestDTO.getToDate()+"'");
        }
        stringBuilder.append(" and buyer_business.buyer_id =  "+" "+buyerId+" ");
        stringBuilder.append(" and purchase_order.purchase_order_status = 'PROCESSED' ");
        stringBuilder.append(" and business_supplier_mapping.deleted is false ");
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()){
            String itemGroupIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and items.item_group_id in ( "+itemGroupIds+" )");
        }
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()){
            String mainItemGroupIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and item_group.main_item_group_id in ( "+mainItemGroupIds+" )");
        }
        if (businessReportRequestDTO.getSupplierIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getSupplierIdList().isEmpty()) {
            String supplierIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getSupplierIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and items.supplier_id in ( " + supplierIds + " )");
        }
        if (businessReportRequestDTO.getBuyerBusinessIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getBuyerBusinessIdList().isEmpty()) {
            String businessIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getBuyerBusinessIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and buyer_business.id in ( " + businessIds + " ) ");
        }
        stringBuilder.append("   group by items.supplier_id");
        Query resultQuery = em.createNativeQuery(stringBuilder.toString());
        List<Object[]> result = resultQuery.getResultList();
        //Query countQuery = em.createNativeQuery(stringBuilder.toString());
        int count= result.size();
        log.info(" SIZE "+count);
        List<TopSupplierItemsDTO> topSupplierItemsDTOList = this.setTopSupplierItemsDTO(result); stringBuilder.append("SELECT sum(amount),supplier.company_name "+
            "FROM purchase_order\n" +
            "LEFT JOIN process_order ON process_order.id=purchase_order.process_order_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN items ON items.id=process_order.items_id ") ;
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()) {
            stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN item_group ON items.item_group_id=item_group.id  ");
        }
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()) {
            stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN main_item_group ON item_group.main_item_group_id=main_item_group.id  ");
        }
        stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN supplier ON items.supplier_id=supplier.id  " +
            "LEFT JOIN buyer_business ON process_order.buyer_business_id = buyer_business.id   ");
        stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN business_supplier_mapping on business_supplier_mapping.supplier_id=supplier.id and business_supplier_mapping.buyer_business_id=process_order.buyer_business_id ");
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getFromDate()!=null && businessReportRequestDTO.getToDate()!=null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(" WHERE (purchase_order.deleted is null OR purchase_order.deleted is false) AND purchase_order.received_date BETWEEN '"+businessReportRequestDTO.getFromDate()+"' AND  '"+businessReportRequestDTO.getToDate()+"'");
        }
        stringBuilder.append(" and buyer_business.buyer_id =  "+" "+buyerId+" ");
        stringBuilder.append(" and purchase_order.purchase_order_status = 'PROCESSED' ");
        stringBuilder.append(" and business_supplier_mapping.deleted is false ");
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()){
            String itemGroupIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and items.item_group_id in ( "+itemGroupIds+" )");
        }
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()){
            String mainItemGroupIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and item_group.main_item_group_id in ( "+mainItemGroupIds+" )");
        }
        if (businessReportRequestDTO.getSupplierIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getSupplierIdList().isEmpty()) {
            String supplierIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getSupplierIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and items.supplier_id in ( " + supplierIds + " )");
        }
        if (businessReportRequestDTO.getBuyerBusinessIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getBuyerBusinessIdList().isEmpty()) {
            String businessIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getBuyerBusinessIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and buyer_business.id in ( " + businessIds + " ) ");
        }
        stringBuilder.append("   group by items.supplier_id");
        Query resultQuery = em.createNativeQuery(stringBuilder.toString());
        List<Object[]> result = resultQuery.getResultList();
        //Query countQuery = em.createNativeQuery(stringBuilder.toString());
        int count= result.size();
        log.info(" SIZE "+count);
        List<TopSupplierItemsDTO> topSupplierItemsDTOList = this.setTopSupplierItemsDTO(result); stringBuilder.append("SELECT sum(amount),supplier.company_name "+
            "FROM purchase_order\n" +
            "LEFT JOIN process_order ON process_order.id=purchase_order.process_order_id " +
            "LEFT JOIN items ON items.id=process_order.items_id ") ;
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()) {
            stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN item_group ON items.item_group_id=item_group.id  ");
        }
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()) {
            stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN main_item_group ON item_group.main_item_group_id=main_item_group.id  ");
        }
        stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN supplier ON items.supplier_id=supplier.id  " +
            "LEFT JOIN buyer_business ON process_order.buyer_business_id = buyer_business.id   ");
        stringBuilder.append("LEFT JOIN business_supplier_mapping on business_supplier_mapping.supplier_id=supplier.id and business_supplier_mapping.buyer_business_id=process_order.buyer_business_id ");
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getFromDate()!=null && businessReportRequestDTO.getToDate()!=null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(" WHERE (purchase_order.deleted is null OR purchase_order.deleted is false) AND purchase_order.received_date BETWEEN '"+businessReportRequestDTO.getFromDate()+"' AND  '"+businessReportRequestDTO.getToDate()+"'");
        }
        stringBuilder.append(" and buyer_business.buyer_id =  "+" "+buyerId+" ");
        stringBuilder.append(" and purchase_order.purchase_order_status = 'PROCESSED' ");
        stringBuilder.append(" and business_supplier_mapping.deleted is false ");
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()){
            String itemGroupIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getItemGroupIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and items.item_group_id in ( "+itemGroupIds+" )");
        }
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList().isEmpty()){
            String mainItemGroupIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getMainItemGroupIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and item_group.main_item_group_id in ( "+mainItemGroupIds+" )");
        }
        if (businessReportRequestDTO.getSupplierIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getSupplierIdList().isEmpty()) {
            String supplierIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getSupplierIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and items.supplier_id in ( " + supplierIds + " )");
        }
        if (businessReportRequestDTO.getBuyerBusinessIdList()!=null && !businessReportRequestDTO.getBuyerBusinessIdList().isEmpty()) {
            String businessIds = businessReportRequestDTO.getBuyerBusinessIdList().stream().map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            stringBuilder.append(" and buyer_business.id in ( " + businessIds + " ) ");
        }
        stringBuilder.append("   group by items.supplier_id");
        Query resultQuery = em.createNativeQuery(stringBuilder.toString());
        List<Object[]> result = resultQuery.getResultList();
        //Query countQuery = em.createNativeQuery(stringBuilder.toString());
        int count= result.size();
        log.info(" SIZE "+count);
        List<TopSupplierItemsDTO> topSupplierItemsDTOList = setTopSupplierItemsDTO(result);
        return new PageImpl<>(topSupplierItemsDTOList, pageable, count);
}
```

The issue is this query takes around 1-2 minutes to execute, which makes it slower. The responsse time is between 1.7 - 1.9 minutes for 6 months range. Is there a way to make it quicker? I heard that using spring data will reduce the speed, but I don't know how to implement it when there is if condition in the query implementation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well don't use `getResultList`, increase the  fetch size through a query hint. I also don't really get the use of a `Page` here as you always retrieve everything.

Comment: Get a DBA to look at the execution of the query and see whether any indexes should be added.

Comment: @tgdavies I have added index to the entities. I got a bit faster, but not as fast as expected.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have changed the code to get a sublist of the List based on the pagination. Haven't added the change here. Adding fetch size - since this is a report, I need to get all values for the filters provided. So, will adding fetch size help?

Comment: Fetch size reduces the number of round trips, thus network calls. The default is 10 (which is low) use something like 1000 or 500 to reduce the network roundtrips. Also if you get a sublist this is is even worse, you get everything and then ditch 80% because you don't need it.

Comment: It will be very difficult to answer your question, because (1) it is not a single query. Depending on which conditions get activated, the resulting queries, as well as their performance will differ wildly, (2) looking at the query alone is not enough, we would need to see what indices exist on the tables, a ballpark figure of the number of records in each table etc. a query plan would also help

Comment: Also, have you tried executing the query against the DB directly? JPA likely isn't the issue

Comment: Yes @crizzis, it takes around 1-2 minutes.